# Unmount inactive screens (reset stacks) in bottom tab navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Im using react-navigation v3, is there an option to make that inactive tab screens get unmounted like unmountInactiveRoutes: true in DrawerNavigator?? I cant find something like unmountInactiveRoutes for BottomTabNavigator.

I have two stacknavigators inside a BottomTabNavigator and I want to unmount them automatically or just reset them.

my navigators:

- BottomTabNavigator

  - stackNavigator
  - stackNavigator

Comment: I have the same question. But I workaround through 'willFocus' companion with other events to get it work. If there is no, this is another choice.

Comment: @JamesLiu would u give me an example pls on how u did it

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ***useIsFocused*** hook to solve your problem. So when the screen is focused you will display your desirable screen otherwise just return null. Check the code below:

```js
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const isFocused = useIsFocused();

if(isFocused) return(/*your screen*/)

else if(!isFocused) return null
```

And if you want to make some fetching or some changes on every focus just use the ***useFocusEffect*** hook.